# How to extend Array in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to extend an Array using prototypes.  How can I do this in Flow?

```
Array.prototype.equals = function(compare): boolean {
  return Array.isArray(compare) && !(this < compare || compare < this);
};
```

So I can do something like this:

```
[1,2,3].equals([1,2,3])
```

Comment: What is Array2? Is this what you're looking for? https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAECCBO8wE8BMAeAKgPmgUwA8AXPAOwBMYElktcBvAKGnwEcBXMECACmAHsAtgAcw8PAEoAXNABG-fiDxhS0Jixbii7eKuooAdAEsI+5HyGjxE6ADJb0AIQ8iACxPR00ASLF5oAD4B3pZ+ntBuJhIA3MzQAL6M8UA

Comment: Hey sorry that was a mistake! Thanks for the comment, I updated the question.

Comment: Seems like still not possible with flow (like many other things)... https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/396

Comment: That explains it, thank you!